# External image can display as WebP Format?

Tags: node.js, nuxt.js, webp, pagespeed-insights

My project is NuxtJS based.

I've been searching but couldn't find anything. In accordance with the working principles of my project, I pull images from external websites to my website via URL.

However, this creates problems in the Lighthouse reports. This is the error: "Serve images in nextgen formats".

Maybe it's silly, but is there a way to publish the images we take from websites in WebP format?

Comment: Download them, convert to webp and serve. If the images you're referencing aren't "next gen formats" then no.

Comment: Unfortunately, the images I took from external websites are not new generation formats.

Comment: Aside from converting and hosting them yourself, then no. Lighthouse will recommend best practices but that's not always possible, so I would ignore it.

Comment: I will do so too. Thank you for your contribution.

Comment: note: Safari browser will not show webP images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `API` services.
They will Convert them automatically for you. but it is only possible if you have a backend side for your website, doing this in frontend is pointless.

Comment: İ have backend as NodeJS. Researching Convert API. Thanks